# How can I show preview image without upload?

Tags: php, jquery, image, cakephp, image-processing

I would like to show preview image without the image is being uploaded. Preferably if I can crop the image first, then show preview. What is the best way to do this? I heard this can be done with jquery and ajax. My website is using cakePHP.

Comment: Google has tons of example for this. Google: "image preview filereader".

Comment: Here is your answer.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/10820214/5292650
I hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

The html code:

```
<input type="file" id="files" />
<img id="image" />
```

The JavaScript code:

```
document.getElementById("files").onchange = function () {
    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = function (e) {
        // get loaded data and render thumbnail.
        document.getElementById("image").src = e.target.result;
    };

    // read the image file as a data URL.
    reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
};
```

You may refer More [Here](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/)